# reverse a linked list non recursive

Tags: python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

Please check the reverse function below. The rest of the code should be fine. The function is not reversing the doubly linked list for some reason.

```
#!/bin/python3
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
```

Doubly linked list Node structure

```
class DoublyLinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self.data = node_data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
```

Doubly linked list structure

```
class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = DoublyLinkedListNode(node_data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            node.prev = self.tail
            self.tail = node
```

Prints the doubly linked list from head to the tail in order.

```
def print_doubly_linked_list(node, sep, fptr):
    while node:
        fptr.write(str(node.data))

        node = node.next

        if node:
            fptr.write(sep)
```

Please check the below reverse function as this function does not return the reversed doubly linked list. Check for any errors and let me know.

```
def reverse(head):
    if head == None:
        return head
    temp = None    
    curr = head
    while(curr is not None):
        temp = curr.prev
        curr.prev = curr.next
        curr.next= temp
        curr = curr.next
    if temp is not None:
        head = temp.prev
    return head




if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        llist_count = int(input())

        llist = DoublyLinkedList()

        for _ in range(llist_count):
            llist_item = int(input())
            llist.insert_node(llist_item)

        llist1 = reverse(llist.head)

        print_doubly_linked_list(llist1, ' ', fptr)
        fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start reversing your list from the `head`, which has no `prev` item and therefore `break`s out of your `while` loop. Instead, reversing from the `tail` should do:

```
llist1 = reverse(llist.tail)
```

In general, I think your function `reverse` should take the whole list (not the head or tail) as an argument, and then build a completely new `DoublyLinkedList` from the items in it. That would also solve the confusion with your variable names, where `llist` is a `DoublyLinkedList` while `llist1` is a `DoublyLinkedListNode`.

**edit**:
I forgot, in `insert_node`, you should also make `self.tail = node` if there hasn't been a `head` yet / first node.

Comment: Except the reverse function I'm not allowed to change anything. It's a hackerrank problem, everything else is sealed.

Comment: Ok. But the way it is, you cannot create a linked list with more than one element - it will try to use the `tail` while it is still `None`.